# Is there a way to create Docker volume and prepopulate it with data?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

My goal is to simulate something like hard drive or USB, that you can prepopulate with data and then mount it to specific Docker container and access it from this container. Ideally, it should provide options such as mounting it in read-only mode.

I tried Docker volumes and the closest I got is something like shared host/container directory mounted as volume, docker-compose file looks like this:

```
...
image: image-name
container_name: container-name
volumes:
  - ./data:/app/data
ports:
  - "3000:3000"
```

Is there any way to do this or is there some better approach? Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need this?

Comment: What's wrong with the host-directory setup you describe in the question?

Answer (score 6):

If you want to populate a volume with data before using it, you can first create it:

```
docker volume create myapplicationdata
```

And then attach it to an ephemeral container in order to populate it with data:

```
tar -C /path/to/my/files -c -f- . | docker run --rm -i -v myapplicationdata:/data alpine tar -C /data -xv -f-
```

To use a pre-existing volume in your `docker-compose.yml`, declare it as an external volume:

```
version: "3"

services:
  myapplication:
    image: image-name
    container_name: container-name
    volumes:
      - myapplicationdata:/app/data
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"

volumes:
  myapplicationdata:
    external: true
```

Comment: shouldn't this be a 'docker run' command before --rm ?

Comment: There is a `docker`, but you're right, it's missing the `run` part. Good catch!

Comment: while not a 'fix', but the full alpine base shouldn't be needed just for populating the volume... busybox should be enough and use less resources (at least in my tests it seems to)

Comment: the swarm allows you to run a container on a different node, the the question asked here is useful to populate a volume on remote node but the answer is using tar to extract files, while a docker stack deploy feature could have been useful to pre populate the volume